# Get View as String from one Controller to Another Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way I can get the view as a string from once controller to another controller.

Ex:

```
public class ControllerA {

    @RequestMapping("/abc")
    public String displayMenu(){
        ...
        return "main.html";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ContorllerB{

    @Autowired
    private ControllerA controllerA;

    @RequestMapping("/xyz")
    public String getJSON(){
        String htmlContent = controllerA.displayMenu();
        convertToJSON(htmlContent);
        ..
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: you seem to mix concepts of model and view here... why can't you obtain model in `ControllerB` and convert it to json instead?

Comment: Actually I need the whole html from ControllerA in ControllerB.

Comment: You probably don't need the HTML in the _controller_. You probably need it in the view (HTML) generated by ControllerB. Check how to build composite views with your view technology, JSP, velocity, thymeleaf, whatever it is.